# Isomorphism between two groups mapping the same elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I need to show that there is an isomorphic function $f:\Bbb Z_6 \to U(14)$ that $f(5)=5$

I can show that $U(14)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$ by showing that $U(14)$ is cyclic of order 6, but I do not know whether this would imply that $\Bbb Z_6$ is isomorphic to $U(14)$. Can I make this inference? Also, how do I now show that $f(5)=5$?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is isomorphic the $H$, by say $f:G \to H$, then $H$ is isomorphic to $G$ by $f^{-1}:H \to G$. So yes, $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is isomorphic to $U(14)$. You can cook up an isomorphism with $f(5)=5$ by finding $g\in U(14)$ such that $g^5=5$, and then set $f(1)=g$, and this determines $f$ on all of $\mathbb{Z}_6$. In fact $g=3$ works since $3^5 = 5 \mod 14$.

Comment: What does setting $f(1)=g$ give tho?

Comment: do you treat $g$ as a number? or as a function?

Comment: I think you also made a mistake

Comment: $g$ is a number that you have to find to do the problem. I ended up finding it for you - take $g=3$. So $f(1)=3$. This gives $f(2)=f(1+1)=f(1)*f(1)=3*3=9$ (since $f$ is a homomorphism) and so on - once you set what $f(1)$ has to be, then this determines $f(2), f(3), f(4), f(5), f(6)$. This works because $Z_6$ is cyclic. Anyways, so $f(5)=3^5=5$ in mod 14.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if there exists an isomorphism f: G ----> G', f^-1 is an isomorphism from G' to G. (If f is a bijection, then it inverse is as well, and t is easy to check that the condition for isomorphisms hold for inv(f).

Comment: Welcome to MSE, perhaps you'll find [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on displaying math helpful.